# New "Email Settings" tab is displayed on other user's profile in mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, email

## Steps to reproduce

1. Log in.
2. Visit other user's profile on mobile web.

## Expected behavior

I do not see "Email Settings" on the profile, as it does on desktop.

## Current behavior

I see them, clicking them results in `404 not found`.

> [image: buggy website]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, this is now fixed in production.

Comment: Fixed for regular users, but the Email Settings tab still shows up for moderators.